# read image from mysql express, node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have an API which upload image into mysql when I send an image binary to this api in mysql it save `http://127.0.0.1:3000/belleza/image-1672036638251.jpg` so when i put this path in hrf of image tag it doesnt load my photo and in console im getting `cannot get http://127.0.0.1:3000/belleza/image-1672036638251.jpg` please can you say me how to read the file or suggest any article about this

```
    app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req,res) => {
    if(!req.file){ 
        console.log('No file upload');
    }else {
        console.log(req.file.filename);
        const imageSRC='http://127.0.0.1:3000/belleza/'+req.file.filename;
        const insertData = 'INSERT INTO users_file(image)VALUES(?)'
        connection.query(insertData,[imageSRC],(err,result) => {
            if(err) throw err
            console.log('file uploaded');
        })
        res.send('file uploaded')
    }
})
```